# Adobe Molehill draw line

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, line, molehill

how can i draw a line with adobe molehill. If i was using opengl i would use GL_LINES, but i seems molehill can only draw triangles.

Cheers

Comment: Though I don't know anything about molehill (now called Stage 3D), maybe a fresh look at the problem would help.   Wouldn't drawing a triangle of zero height be the same as a line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing lines with GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458185/drawing-lines-with-glsl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Molehill is triangles only, because only triangles are hardware accelerated on most consumer video cards. You can draw thin rectangle with two triangles. Not sure if [Molehill 2D](https://github.com/egreenfield/M2D) already supports lines, but it may be worth to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a fragment shader that will only draw along one edge of your triangle.